# Location of SQLite database file in WAMP when trying to work on SQLite using PHP?

Tags: php, database, sqlite, wamp

I'm trying to create a database in SQLite using PHP.
I've WAMP Installed and it has PHP 5.3 and it supports SQLite.
I'm able to create databases and tables using PHP functions for SQLite.
But i want to know , what is the the location of database file(.db / .sql) for SQLite in WAMP.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a specific place under Windows where these files belong; a sibling of the document root usually suffices.